# How to change Yakuake shortcut key?

Tags: 11.10, kubuntu, shortcut-keys

I've just installed yakuake in kubuntu 11.10, but cannot see it in the "Custom Shortcuts" settings.

How to change shortcut to <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> in this case?

Comment: We need to maintain the questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).Regards,

Comment: @BlueXrider: Yes, and how the possibility of changing shortcut is not helpful for community? I'm stackexchange member for about 2 years and I do know what and how to ask. If you don't like it - perform close request, that is what it was developed for.

Comment: Hey guys, I'm bountying this since @zerkms is still looking for an answer. As for abandoned, we are attempting to clean up the site. [Meta post here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2651/ask-ubuntu-clean-up).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can still configure the Global shortcut in the application itself.

Launch yakuake.
In its menu (In my theme the little triangle between "pin" and "close" at the lower right corner) you will be able to select the entry "Configure Shortcut..."

Here you will be able to select your preferred Shortcut in the Global column (by default F12 key)

Same for other KDE applications, as far as I seen, you can select the global Shortcut from the application itself.

Comment: Ahhh The terminal window itself was covering the option!

Comment: Works on KDE of Xenial

Comment: @kieveli how did you get to that when the terminal was covering the option?

Comment: @wranvaud I think I set an option to have the terminal in a window instead? Does that sound possible?

Comment: @kieveli I can't get to the options/configurations now, I just don't see them, it looks like my yakuake terminal is full screen hiding all menus. The only thing I can access is the contextual menu when I right click... Thanks for the reply I'll see if I find that option

Comment: Shift+Alt+Arrow up = this will reduce the height of yakuake (in case part of it is below the screen height) and you will see the menu appear at the bottom!